# I cloned My KYC to Wallet Connect But its not working

Tags: laravel

Hello everyone please i clone my KYC Page to Wallet Connect, were users can submit information and it would reflect on the admin side just as the KYC works,i have duplicated everything and changed the names were its applicable but i am getting errors from the client side and the admin side, please i would be happy if you can assist me it would go a long way

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibaYG.png)I tried adding a wallet connect to my HYIP website and it's[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMr8K.png) returning this error

```
compact('type', 'operator', 'query', 'boolean');
```

in /home/investmentsite/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/Backend/WalletController.php (line 108)
* @return Application|Factory|View     */    public function edit($id)    {        $Wallet = Wallet::find($id);        return view('backend.wallet.edit', compact('wallet'));    }    /**     * Remove the specified resource from storage.     *

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSZfN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you variable is uppercase while you are passing a lowercase variable so just do either one of the following

```
compact('Wallet');
```

or change the variable name

```
$wallet = (...)
return view(...)->compact('wallet');
```

UPDATE 1#:
So from your comment my guess is that this will be your solution

```
$wallet = Wallet::findOrFail($id);
return view('backend.wallet.edit', compact('wallet'));
```

Comment: I have tried this is not working, i would love if you can helpme look into it, i can share the cpanel access if thats okay

Comment: I hope you did not just copy my answer with the (...), that is where you put your code that already is written, if you need me I can update the answer, provide more info about the problem you are having

Comment: No i did not, i am making the change as you said but the code error is changing


Undefined variable $wallet (View: /home/investmentsite/public_html/resources/views/backend/wallet/edit.blade.php)

Comment: I have updated the answer just C/P and it should work, cheers!

Comment: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

 $walletCredential = array_merge($input['wallet_credential'], ['wallet_type_of_name' => $wallet->name, 'wallet_time_of_time' => now()]);        $user = \Auth::user();        if ($user->wallet_credential) {            foreach (json_decode($user->wallet_credential, true) as $key => $value) {                self::delete($value);            }        }        foreach ($walletCredential as $key => $value) {

Comment: Well my friend that is a completely different question. If the above answer solved you first issue close this question and post a new one!

Comment: thanks the formis sending from the user side, am trying to view it from the admin side and i keep geting this error 


DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Exception Message:

Undefined variable $wallet_time (view: /home/investmentsite/public_html/resources/views/backend/wallet/include/_time.blade.php)

Comment: let me do that now

Comment: Just post a new question and I can see if I can help

Comment: it said i should wait for 90mins

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Exception Message:

Undefined variable $wallet_time (view: /home/investmentsite/public_html/resources/views/backend/wallet/include/_time.blade.php)


any advise here?

Comment: Its related to the same question sir

Comment: Do you have the wallet_time variable setup for that view?

Comment: how doi do that,like i said i cloned everything that was kyc related

Comment: You missed that part then, go back and find how that variable is used, and I always recommend writing everything from scratch instead of copying everything!

Comment: how do i do this wallet_time variable setup for that view?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74773848/i-cant-view-submitted-datas i have posted it

Comment: Hello Please look at the link i shared please